# External swf doesn't load onto a stage via UIloader

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a typical logo on the right top corner and a menu bar just above it. Above the menu bar, I have a `UIloader` in which I load `photoalbum.swf` when one of the menu buttons is pressed. The problem is that setting the `scaleContent` property to true doesn't load my external swf.

Setting it to `false`, everything appears as expected, except that the bottom part of my photo album is cut since the `scaleContent` property set to false (this makes the loaded swf file's size the same as the stage's and as the `UIloader` begins just above the menu, the bottom part gets cut off).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... not sure what UILoader is, but how about simply using the `Loader` class instead? It's a built-in Flash class that you can use to load SWF files:

```
var l:Loader = new Loader();
l.load(new URLRequest("http://example.com/somefile.swf")
addChild(l);
```

Then you can resize the content any way you want. I know that there are plenty of frameworks on top of basic AS3 but sometime it saves a lot of time to come back to basics.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did it with Loader object and nothing. When i set Loader height parameter to 500, my loaded swf cannot be seen. It only can be seen when i don't set the height parameter. As the ac3 documentation says : "A SWF file or image loaded into a Loader object inherits the position, rotation, and scale properties of the parent display objects of the Loader object." And also the dimensions as I can guess from experience of my problem. That's why setting the width and height does not work ???

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height of loader only after swf is completely loaded.
so, you have to wait for swf load complete and then set width and height.

```
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadComplete);
addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("somefile.swf"));

private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
loader.width=400;
loader.height=400;
}
```